# How to use ReFS on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ntfs, refs

I want to try out Windows 10s new file system [ReFS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview). I have the latest Windows 10 Pro installed and created 2 **vhdx** virtual drives, as listed below:

[image]

But in the file system combo box for creating a storage, I can't find `ReFS`. Does anyone know how I can activate this?

[image]

The screenshot below is from an online [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/311840/what-is-refs-the-resilient-file-system-on-windows/) where `ReFS` should be listed:

[image]

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are you using? Consumer editions (Home and Professional) most likely cannot use it.

Comment: I use Windows Professional. Do I really need the enterprise for that? :-o

Comment: Refs is for servers at this point. I do not see a Windows 10 implementation yet (not even on Windows Insider)

Comment: @John - It’s offered on Windows 10 Pro for Workstations.  Directly from the link article: **ReFS functionality is now available as part of Windows 10 Pro for Workstations as well as Windows 10 Enterprise.** ReFs isn’t a new feature it’s from 2016 builds.  Pro for Workstations isn’t new either.

Comment: I just found this: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/microsoft-to-remove-full-refs-support-win10-pro.html `Microsoft Removed Full ReFS Support from Win10`

Comment: I did not see that at all. I looked at several sites.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I can confirm they are `vhdx`, not `vhd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to try out Windows 10s new file system ReFS. I have the latest Windows 10 Pro installed and created 2 vhdx virtual drives, as listed below:

ReFS is almost more than a decade old if you consider the fact Windows 8 was the first version of Windows to support it.

Unless you are running Windows 10 Enterprise or Windows 10 Professional for Workstations you won’t be able to create a new ReFS volume.  Supported versions of Windows Server obviously also natively support the creation of ReFS volumes.

> Does anyone know how I can activate this?

You must be using Windows 10 Professional for Workstations

> Creation ability will be available in the following editions only: Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Pro for Workstations. Creation ability will be removed from all other editions. All other editions will have Read and Write ability.

An alternative solution to upgrading would be to format the virtual VHDXs as ReFS on a supported edition and simply attach them on an Windows edition that doesn’t directly fully support it.

Source: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-removed-features)